# Spring BasicProcessingFilter migration to spring security 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We are migrating from earlier Spring Security 2.x version to the latest 4.x version. Earlier we were using `org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter` class. As part of the Spring security dependency update we are not seeing the corresponding class in the latest release. Similarly we found the same issue with `org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter` class.

Can someone let me know what we need to fix to retrofit the existing classes with the new jar.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in Spring Security 4.x is [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.html).